# What is this "bulbous"/"blood sugar" test tube used for?

Tags: equipment, identification

I was at an antique and bric-a-brac store, and I found several pieces of glassware. They were pretty cheap, so I purchased some of the more interesting ones. Among them were a few somewhat strange "bulbous test tubes". I purchased 2 of them, and on sale for $2.50 each.(the blue line means half off).

Here they are: [image: full test tube]
[image: labels]

After looking up "kimax 47121" I found [an amazon listing for some](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AC7RPD6), labeled as a "blood sugar tube". I could not find anything else besides this. Are they particularly useful, for anything besides stuff relating blood sugar? How are they used? Can I heat them without fear of it breaking? Would they be worth trying to sell if I cannot use them?

Answers to any of these questions would be great.